# MySQL return all column names in uppercase

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have SQL query, just to simplify it, imagine having columns `id`, `name`, `pass` in table users and I want database to return these column names in uppercase like ID,NAME,PASS. I know that i can A) rename columns in database B) select it in uppercase like
`SELECT ID,NAME,PASS FROM users` ... But I need to use it like this: `SELECT * FROM users`. I tried to use something like `SELECT UPPER(*) FROM users`, but it gives me syntax error.

To clarify: I need column **names** in uppercase, not column values!

**MY SOLUTION:**
So after many tries I have done it through PHP after fetching results. Guess It's easier, so I called function    [array_change_key_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php)    which returns keys of array in satisfied key case (obviously keys of this array were also column names)

Comment: Do you want to return the column **names** in upper case or column **values**? Changing column names and typing them upper case in select statements affect column names. Upper() function affects column values.

Comment: @Shadow yeah, I just realized that it affects values, not column names. I need column **names** in uppercase

Comment: if the ultimate goal is to simply echo those in a query and possibly in an HTML table, why not just do it with PHP with `strtoupper()`?

Comment: So, thoughts on ^ are what? Given the answers, there's no interaction on your part, or an accepted answer.

Comment: I love it when they leave like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrive all the column names of a specific table in upper case you can use the following query:

```
SELECT UPPER(`COLUMN_NAME`) 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

If you want to get uppercase column names in some result set of a select query, you have to create the columns in upper case, or you can upper them in your php script, but it's not possible to make them uppercase in the resultset dynamically for all columns.

Comment: I take it from your edit *"or you can upper them in your php script"* that you've seen [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577893/mysql-return-all-column-names-in-uppercase#comment58842571_35577893) about doing it with PHP. OP's not responding neither.

Comment: Yes, but this is only a side note because the question is about doing it on DB side. Maybe it is still possible with some sort of joining the information schema into the select and uppercase the column names?

Comment: Maybe... just maybe. However, OP isn't responding to my comment about that. So they're either ignoring it and waiting for a magic answer (which won't happen, not from me anyway), or they're heavily concentrating on trying to make things work, or has said *"F-this, I'll (whatever)"*. Your answer so far, is the forerunner ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in sql to automatically upper case field names in a resultset using `select * ...`, unless you define them as upper case in the create table itself.

In php, however, you can dynamically create the select statement, that queries all field names of a table using [information_schema.columns table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) and places the column names in allcap format into the sql statement or just format them when you output the field names in php.